# Optimize Scala JSON Parsing

Tags: scala

I am working on a Spark Streaming Application that is taking in a JSON message and needs to parse it. It has two parts but part of the JSON parsing seems to be the larger overhead when testing. Is there any way to optimize this?

```
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON

val parsed = JSON.parseFull(formatted)
val subject = parsed.flatMap(_.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]].get("subject")).toString.drop(5).dropRight(1)
val predicate = parsed.flatMap(_.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]].get("predicate")).toString.drop(5).dropRight(1)
val obj = parsed.flatMap(_.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]].get("object")).toString.drop(5).dropRight(1)
val label = parsed.flatMap(_.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]].get("label")).toString.drop(5).dropRight(1)
val url = "http://" + elasticAddress.value + "/data/quad/"
val urlEncoded = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(label + subject + predicate + obj, "utf-8")
```

Comment: parsed.flatMap(_.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]] is getting repeated. Could be computed and reused

Comment: Can the parsed be reused? because .get is happening inside the flatmap?

Comment: Yes, perform the get on the computed value after applying map.

Comment: That doesnt seem to work? al parsed = JSON.parseFull(formatted).flatMap(_.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]]) does not allow a .get

Comment: Also, if you use some good json library for parsing, you can avoid the unseemly asInstanceOf code.

Comment: I'll just use json4s instead to make it easier.

Comment: This looks like semi manual parsing to me. Why not use a tool like Argonaut/Circe?

Comment: `scala.util.parsing.json` is unsuitable for serious use

Comment: Yeah, seems like I will go after a community library like json4s to do my bidding.

Answer (score 0):

Are you also using the Play framework in your project?  If so, [the Play JSON library](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson) can definitely cut down on your code to make things more readable (like easy casting to a `case class` with matching structure), though I don't know offhand how well it will optimize things for you from an efficiency standpoint.

Comment: I have been using json4s which I think I'll switch over to.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed it to this:

```
import org.json4s.JsonAST.{JField, JObject, JString, JArray, JValue}
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.

        val parsed = parse(data)
        val output: List[(String, String, String, String)] = for {
          JArray(sys) <- parsed
          JObject(child) <- sys
          JField("subject", JString(subject)) <- child
          JField("predicate", JString(predicate)) <- child
          JField("object", JString(obj)) <- child
          JField("label", JString(label)) <- child
        } yield (subject, predicate,obj, label)
        val subject = output(0)._1
        val predicate = output(0)._2
        val obj = output(0)._3
        val label = output(0)._4
```